# p5.js how to translate along axes after rotate

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation, translate-animation, p5.js

After I rotated an coordinates system it is translating along its new axes. Is it somehow possible to translate it along axes before rotation?

Idea is that user uploads an image and then he can rotate it, zoom it and move it around the middle of the viewport. Somehow I failt o achive all of those functions ta once.

Any suggestions?

EDIT

I.e. there is a canvas. I draw an image there. Then I rotate it 90° and I want to translate it on X axis. It moves down the screen. Because axes are turned around.

EDIT

Here is a code snippet that I use for transformation. Image is rotated always in it's (0,0) point. That is why I translate it in a way that it is rotatet in its middle point. Afterwards I draw the image in an offset point.

```
    p.push();
        p.translate(canvasWidth/2, canvasHeight/2);
        p.rotate(angle * p.TWO_PI/360);

        var x = -loadedImage.width/2  - offsetX;
        var y = -loadedImage.height/2 - offsetY;

        p.image(loadedImage, x, y);
    p.pop();
```

EDIT

I decied to translate first, and then rotate. It makes translating correct but it rotates around wrong pivot point. I can't have everything I guess.

Comment: Do you want to rotate around the origin of the object or the origin of the screen?

Comment: Origin of the screen. I.e. there is a canvas. I draw an image there. Then I rotate it 90° and I want to translate it on X axis. It moves down the screen. Because axes are turned around.

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.translate(100,0);
ctx.rotate(20 * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
ctx.restore();
ctx.fillRect(100,0,50,50);
```

try this code:Use drawImage instead of fillRect in your code

Comment: It gives two images. I want to manipulate one image uploaded by the user. Like a small cropping/editing tool. It is harder than i thought. I decied to translate first, and then rotate. It makes translating correct but it rotates around wrong pivot point. I can't have everything I guess.

Comment: var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.translate(100,0);
ctx.rotate(20 * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
ctx.restore();   Just remove the last fillRect.  I have to know which position you want rotate

Comment: Thx for your time. I want to rotate and translate in any direction and in any order. User uploads an image. Drags image around, rotates in both directions and then sends it to the server.

Comment: For your requirement dont need to write a code.These all easy by plugin,I recommend fabric.js will accomplish all your needs  Here is a link http://fabricjs.com/

Comment: Thx, I will take a look at it. It does not change the fact that I want to know how people solve this issue.

Comment: First you have to drawImage as object in canvas,and then warp image into editing button like resize,rotate,move.Then add action to each button.For example If you write code for move button,First you have to find out image is selected or not ,if it is then find the x,y position of mouse,then move the image according to mouse move,when the mouse up stop moving the image that is the procedure.If i do with an demo it will  take huge time.